# Collections.emptySet() vs new HashSet<>()

Tags: java, collections, hashset, is-empty

How can I validate if the Set is empty set or new HashSet<>() ?
Tried two approaches -

1. `size`
2. `CollectionUtils.isEmpty()`
   Both result in same value.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: `set == Collections.EMPTY_SET`

Answer (score 6):

Of course, a fresh `new HashSet<>()` is empty, and so is `Set.of()` or `Collections.emptySet()`. The point is: **Both are empty sets**, I have no idea why you would want to tell the difference between these two.

The one difference is that `new HashSet<>()` is empty now but may not be empty later (it can be changed; you can add things to it), whereas as per the spec, the result of `Set.of()` or `Collections.emptySet()`, they are empty now and will be empty later: You can't add anything to them, calling .add on them will cause a runtime exception.

That's tantamount to asking: How do I know if it is immutable. You unfortunately basically can't, so that goes right back to: Why would you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.emptySet()` returns a static class `EmptySet`within `java.util.Collections` but `new HashSet<>()` returns a `java.util.HashSet` class. Both collections will be empty, i.e., size = 0 after instantiated but you can distinguish those two by calling `.getClass()` which will return:

```
class java.util.Collections$EmptySet
class java.util.HashSet
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .getClass to see the different implementation that was used.

Answer (score -2):

I got one utility method that can be used to perform the operation -

Collections.EMPTY_SET.equals(mySet)

Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: That’s wrong. `Collections.EMPTY_SET.equals(new HashSet<>())` will evaluate to `true`. Apparently, you got the idea from somewhere else and used it without really understanding, and without even re-checking the result. That’s called Cargo Cult Programming. The correct term is `Collections.EMPTY_SET == mySet` to check whether it is not just equal but the same object.